# Django auth.User in Admininterface: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User found

Tags: django, django-admin, foreign-keys, typeerror

I'm pretty new to django. I try to use the auth.User object as a foreign key.

My model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

(...)

class Entry(models.Model):
    (...)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

When creating a new Entry with a user in admin interface, i get: `"coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User found"`

> Exception Type:   TypeError
>
> Exception Value:   coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User
>   found
>
> Exception
>   Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py
>   in force_unicode, line 71

What am i missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

this should work and explain itself

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.user)
```