# Django: error with "username" in my custom user model - 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: django-models, django-admin, django-users

I'm new with Django and I'm having some problems creating a custom user model. I followed every steps from the django documentation. Here is my model :

```
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
comment = models.BooleanField()
score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
profilpic = models.ImageField(upload_to="/profilepics")
bio = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

Then I created several users with django-registration. But when I go to the admin and I try to delete a user I created or when I just try to click on the username, I get this error:

```
AttributeError at /admin/auth/user/3/
'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'username'
Exception Value:    
'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'username'
Exception Location: /Users/marc-antoinelacroix/Desktop/Site/sportdub/projet/models.py in   __unicode__, line 14
```

So I think I have to create a "username" in my UserProfile model, and associate it to the username of the django's User, but I have no idea how to do it...

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to access

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username
```

but it has to be

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user
```

---

Here's a demo

**project/account/models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    homepage = models.URLField(verify_exists=False)
    #...

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

**project/account/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from account.models import UserProfile

admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]

admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

**project/settings.py**

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "account.userprofile"
```

Comment: Hi. I tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work, I still get the exact same error. It comes from __unicode__ apparently. But thanks!

Comment: what is in line14 of this file? `sportdub/projet/models.py in   __unicode__, line 14`

Comment: and 15? ...or could you post the whole `models.py` file from your `projet` folder?

Comment: thank you, I did try to access return self.username. I replaced it bu return self.user, but know I get the error: TypeError at /admin/auth/user/3/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User found

Comment: Ok, and I found the solution for this error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399283/django-auth-user-in-admininterface-coercing-to-unicode-need-string-or-buffer

Comment: changed `return self.username` to `return self.user.username`. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to define `UserProfile.__unicode__()` properly. It needs to get the username from the related `User` model.

Comment: Ok, what I currently have is: 
 def __unicode__(self):
  return self.username       How do I relate it to the username? Do I have to use "username" as an argument for __unicode()__?