# Why am I getting this Django TypeError?

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError at /admin/KSUvity/activity/add/ coercing to Unicode: need
>   string or buffer, User found

models.py:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="owner")
    college = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    startDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    endDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    attendee = models.ManyToManyField(Attendee, related_name="attendees",null=True, blank=True)
    volunteer = models.ManyToManyField(Volunteer, related_name="volunteers",null=True, blank=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now= True)
    modified_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.title, self.description)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        return super(Activity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Attendee(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="attendee")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student
```

In forms.py:

```
class ActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ('type', 'title', 'description', 'owner', 'college', 'location', 'room', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'attendee', 'volunteer', )
```

From the admin page, I used to get an activity form and add activities.
But I suddenly started to get this error.
What might the problem be?

Comment: Are you leaving your owner field empty? if you want to do that, you have to `null=True, blank=True` where you have created the owner field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django auth.User in Admininterface: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399283/django-auth-user-in-admininterface-coercing-to-unicode-need-string-or-buffer)

Comment: try to change `def __str__(self): return self.student` to `def __str__(self): return '%s' % self.student`

Comment: @AbhishekMenon I am not leaving the owner field empty since I'm not getting the form because of this error.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Tried that solution but it did not work for me.

Comment: @SancaKembang Your solution worked thank you! Add it as an official answer so I can mark it.

Comment: You can rename `attendee` to `attendees` and `volunteer` to `volunteers`. It will make the queries more comprehensible using plural nouns, as they are m2m fields. And please fix the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.student
```

To

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % self.student
```